# Error in producing the output for the json for a specific id value

Tags: python, json

I have the following json tree.

```
json_tree ={
  "Garden": {
    "Seaside": {
      "@loc": "127.0.0.1",
      "@myID": "1.3.1",
      "Shoreside": {
        "@myID": "3",
        "InfoList": {
          "Notes": {
            "@code": "0",
            "@myID": "1"
          },
          "Count": {
            "@myID": "2",
            "@val": "0"
          }
        },
        "state": "0",
        "Tid": "3",
        "Lakesshore": {
          "@myID": "4",
          "InfoList": {
            "Notes": {
              "@code": "0",
              "@oid": "1"
            },
            "Count": {
              "@myID": "2",
              "@val": "0"
            }
          },
          "state": "0",
          "Tid": "4"
        }
      },
      "state": "0",
      "Tid": "2"
    },
    "Tid": "1",
    "state": "0"
  }
}
```

I have a method which takes in the "Tid" value and returns the output in the following format.

This is where the issue lies. I do not understand why for the value of `Tid = 2`, I get "ERROR" stating that the `InfoList` not exists. For other Tid values, it works well. Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

There is NO `InfoList` at "Tid:"2 but I am not sure on how to update my logic to handle this.

```
def get_output (d, id):
    if isinstance(d, dict) and d.get('id') == id:
        yield {"Tid": d['Tid'], "Notes": d['InfoList']['Notes']['@code'], "status": d['state']}
    for i in getattr(d, "values", lambda: [])():
        yield from get_based_on_id(i, id)

# The id is from 2 and higher
key_list = list(get_output (json_tree, id))
# To create the json result
jsonify(key_list if not key_list else key_list[0])
```

```
For "Tid" values of 2 and higher the get_output method creates this output:

{
  "Tid": "3", 
  "Notes": "2000", 
  "state": "2"
}
```

This part shown below works well. The issue is ONLY with the code shown above.

```
def get_output_id_1 (d, id):   
    if isinstance(d, dict) and d.get('id') == id:
        yield {"id": d['Tid'], "state": d['state']}
    for i in getattr(d, "values", lambda: [])():
        yield from get_root_id(i, id)
```

```
For "Tid" value of 1 and higher the get_output_id_1 method creates this output:

{
  "Tid": "1", 
  "state": "1", 
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @C.Nivs Yes, there is no "InfoList", and I am not sure on how to update my current code logic to handle this

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment, I was re-reading the code and thought I was missing something, I'll put it back for context

Comment: Your `json_tree` at the level where `Tid==2` is missing the `InfoList` key: `json_tree['Garden']['Seaside'].keys(); dict_keys(['@loc', '@myID', 'Shoreside', 'state', 'Tid'])`

Comment: Is every `Tid` supposed to associate with an `InfoList`? For example, which `InfoList` should be used for a `Tid` value of 2?

Comment: The Tid is there for every node in the json tree. For tid=2 there is no Infolist and thats why I am unable to return the result.Sorry for delay in response

Comment: @Ajax1234May you help?

Comment: @C.Nivs Any updates for me? I would appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198601/discussion-between-laura-smith-and-c-nivs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using direct access to leverage a key that may or may not be in the dictionary. To get around this, use the `dict.get` method, which will return `None` or some default value that you specify in case the key isn't present:

```py
small_example = {
    'Tid': '2', 
    'status': 'some status'
}

# there is no InfoList key here, so to get around that, I can use something like:
info_list = small_example.get('InfoList')

repr(info_list)
None
```

Now, you can specify a default return value for `get` if you need to chain things together, like with a nested dictionary call:

```py
{
    'Tid': small_example['Tid'],
    'Notes': small_example.get('InfoList', {}).get('Notes', {}).get('@code'),
    'status': small_example.get('state')
}
```

See how on the first two calls, I return an empty dictionary in case `InfoList` and/or `Notes` are missing, which supports the subsequent call to `get`. Without that, I would get an `AttributeError`:

```py
small_example.get('InfoList').get('Notes')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

So your `yield` statement should look like:

```py
yield {
    "Tid": d['Tid'], 
    "Notes": d.get('InfoList', {}).get('Notes', {}).get('@code'), 
    "status": d.get('state')
}
```

### Edit: What if you want a different default for `Notes`?

This gets a little tricky, especially if you want a data structure that doesn't support `.get`, such as `str`.

Your `yield` statement might have to be produced from a different function to make things a little more tidy:

```py
# d is expected to be a dictionary
def create_yield(d):
    # I'm using direct access on `Tid` because I'm assuming it should
    # always be there, and if not it will raise a KeyError, you can
    # modify this to fit your use case
    container = {'Tid': d['Tid'],
                 'status': d.get('state')}

    notes = small_example.get('InfoList', {}).get('Notes')
    # if notes is a dict (not None), then we can get `@code` from it
    if notes is not None:
        container['Notes'] = notes.get('@code')
    # otherwise, don't set the `Notes` attribute

    return container



# later in your code at your yield statement
# you can call this function instead of manually building the dictionary
yield create_yield(small_example)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the clear explanation. I appreciate it alot. :)

Comment: I just had a quick question, is it possible to set the default value to "ToSet" in ```{
    'Tid': small_example['Tid'],
    'Notes': small_example.get('InfoList', {}).get('Notes', {}).get('@code'),
    'status': small_example.get('state')
}``` when the ```Notes``` is not defined? Please let me know. Thank you

Comment: It's possible, however, you'll want to re-do your string of operations. `str` types don't support the `get` operation, so you'd raise an `AttributeError` if you try to get `@code` and `Notes` didn't exist. I'll modify my answer to give you an example, one second

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: yield create_yield(small_example), can I call it with passing the dictionary ```d``` as an arguement?

Comment: `small_example` in this case is the same dictionary I defined above, `d` is expected to be a dictionary

Comment: I just had another question. For instance, I just thought of something which would make more sense. Can we continue in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198953/discussion-between-laura-smith-and-c-nivs).